# Draw a lightning bolt between two given points in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw a lightning bolt which starts at a point and its sharp edge ending at another point. For instance, let me define the points

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p1) at (1,3);
\coordinate (p2) at (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now how do I plot a Lightning bolt between p1 and p2. I know how to draw it explicitly calculating co-ordinates with respect to (1,3) and (5,5). However, if this values change, the calculation has to be re-done again which is not a clean solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a `lightning bolt` decoration. It's not hugely customizable as it stands, as all the dimensions of the bolt are determined by the distance between the two points:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{lightning bolt}{draw}{
\state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength]{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength*0.6}%
    {-\pgfdecoratedpathlength*.1}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength*0.55}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength*0.4}%
    {\pgfdecoratedpathlength*.1}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedpathlength*0.45}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathclose%
}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\p=rnd*75+25;\q=rnd*75+25;}] in {1,...,50}
  \fill [yellow!\p!orange!\q!blue, decoration=lightning bolt, decorate] 
  (rand*4, rand*4) -- ++ (rand*180:rnd*4+2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a `lightning bolt to` path:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{lightning bolt to/.style={to path={
let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikztotarget), \n1={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in
  (\p1) -- ($($(\p1)!0.6!(\p2)$)!\n1*.1!-90:(\p2)$) -- ($(\p1)!0.55!(\p2)$) --
  (\p2) -- ($($(\p1)!0.4!(\p2)$)!\n1*.1!90:(\p2)$) -- ($(\p1)!0.45!(\p2)$) -- 
  cycle (\p2)% Move to end point
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\p=rnd*75+25;\q=rnd*75+25;}] in {1,...,50}
  \fill [yellow!\p!orange!\q!blue]
  (rand*4, rand*4) to [lightning bolt to] ++ (rand*180:rnd*4+2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before (apart from the randomness).

Answer (score 7):

Here a starting point for you usgin the `pic` environment. You can pass two coordinates to the `pic` and so control the start- and end-point of your lightning-path.

The following code uses static offsets to draw the zig-zag `(-.25 and .25)` whicht could be replaced by a dynamically calculated value. This could pretty up the lighting when used in different lengths and scales.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  pics/lightning/.style 2 args={code={
    \draw [thick, arrows={-Stealth[scale=2]}] (#1) -- 
               ($(#1)!.5!(#2) + (.25,-.25)$) -- 
               ($(#1)!.5!(#2) + (-.25,.25)$) --
               (#2);
  }}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {lightning={0,2}{0,0}};
    \pic [blue] {lightning={1,3}{1,-1}};
    \pic [red] {lightning={0,3}{-2,0}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]